# Where are my files in the Explorer when I move them in the Secure Folder [SAMSUNG]

Tags: adb, samsung, file-system, file-management

When I connect my phone (Samsung) to my computer, I see an image in DCIM\Screenshots. When I enable Secure Folder and move the image there, the image disappears in Windows Explorer. When I look at the path where the image is, it still says DCIM\Screenshots but it's not there.

Does anyone know where these files are stored then?
Are they stored somewhere else at all, or are they simply invisible in Explorer?

I already installed ADB and enabled USB debugging on the phone. I think it's the path I'm giving.
I don't know how to specify the drive in the path, or does it not have to be done?
I have already tried these commands:

`adb shell ls -la /phone/DCIM/Screenshots`

`adb shell ls -la user/phone/DCIM/Screenshots`

`adb shell ls -la "Dieser PC/user/phone/DCIM/Screenshots"`

Then I get the error twice that the path is not found.
Is it because the path contains a space?

Comment: You simply tried the wrong paths. The paths shown in Explorer starts with a virtual path that only exists when accessing device via MTP so they don't exist via adb. Instead of `/sdcard` you can try `/storage/emulated/0`. This should work unless your device is very old or Samsung has modified the system to use a different path.

Comment: It works partially now. It says the folder exists but doesn't contain any files. If the folder outside of the Sercre folder contains a file in the folder of the same name, only this will be displayed, but a total of 500 will be counted. Can I also display them in the Serce Folder?